# Kotlin Coroutines Flow with Room run again whenever device back to active

Tags: android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm facing a very strange behavior when using Kotlin Coroutines Flow, Room and Live Data. Whenever I turn off my device for about 5-10s and turn it back on, the Coroutines Flow re-run all over again without any trigger. I'm not sure if it's a feature provided by Google or not. My code is as below.

**MainActivity**

```
wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)

wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->

    words?.let { adapter.setWords(it) }

})
```

**WordViewModel**

```
class WordViewModel(private val repository: WordRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val allWords = repository.allWords.onEach { Log.v("WordViewModel", "Flow trigger again") }.asLiveData()

}
```

**WordRepository**

```
class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {

    val allWords: Flow<List<Word>> = wordDao.getAlphabetizedWords()

    suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
}
```

**WordDao**

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<Word>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)
}
```

**Word**

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
data class Word(@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "word") val word: String)
```

The LogCat `V/WordViewModel: Flow trigger again` will be printed out again when I turn off my device for about 5-10s and turn it back on. Also, the device I'm using to test is Sony XZ2 run on Android 10.

If anyone know why this is happening, please help me understand. Thanks and sorry for my english.

**EDIT**

As the answer from @Alex Krafts, this feature is provided by Google. But because of my Kotlin Coroutines Flow will be combine with a network request. Therefore, I don't want it run again when device become active. I wrote a custom asLiveData() extension function for this case as follow.

**LiveDataExtension**

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.asLiveData(scope: CoroutineScope): LiveData<T> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<T>()
    scope.launch {
        collect {
            liveData.value = it
        }
    }
    return liveData
}
```

**WordViewModel**

```
class WordViewModel(private val repository: WordRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val allWords = repository.allWords.onEach { Log.v("WordViewModel", "Flow trigger again") }.asLiveData(viewModelScope)

}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you wrote your own extension. The existing `asLiveData()` extension takes a `CoroutineContext` as first argument. So, you could have easily done the following, without a custom implementation.
`val allWords = repository.allWords.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)`

Comment: Hi @ASP, the reason I wrote my own extension is to avoid upstream flows re-executed when live data is active again. My flows is a combination of network requests and database queries, so it kinda expensive to re-run the whole thing.

Comment: Yeah, I understood the intention. I was just wondering, why you re-implemented an already existing functionality. What's missing/misbehaving in the existing implementation, that you needed? The only thing you're missing in your initial usage of `.asLiveData()` was to provide `viewmodelScope.coroutineContext` as parameter.
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata

Comment: The ```.asLiveData()``` function provided by Google collect the flow every time LiveData active and cancel when they inactive which cause the re-run behavior. Mine in other hand, only collect once when view model init and cancel when view model is cleared. You can refer to this ```CoroutineLiveData``` file for more info. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/7a4525ac3c56adff5e0de713ca54eae89518e28c/lifecycle/livedata/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/CoroutineLiveData.kt#169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is indeed provided by Google. You are providing `MainActivity`(this) as `LifecycleOwner` in

```
wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->
```

so when you turn off device screen, activity (due to its own lifecycle) stops observing `allWords` and observe it again when you turn device screen back on. So that's where your logs come from.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata)

> After a cancellation, if the LiveData becomes active again, the upstream flow collection will be re-executed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Alex Krafts. It may be not a good behavior if the coroutine flow combine with a network request. Right now to overcome this, I have to use a custom asLiveData() extension function instead of the default one.